# Running windows program at startup without installing it

Tags: windows-10

I have a program that doesn't install its just click and run.Is there a way in windows 10 where i can run the program every time the system boots or startup without have to click and run it each time.

Its sync and backup program we do take back up and sync once in two days where we dont want to copy everything. it similar to rsync linux counterpart

Comment: What do you mean by "click and run"? What exactly are you clicking? What is the program?

Comment: If feasible, run it as a Service to do what you want:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=8Ojo2M-HhzE

Comment: @DavidPostill its a sync program

Comment: @John im watching the video but meanwhile the program I have is it doesn;t install..the moment i exit it closes down all the settings are gone.If i have to use again then redo the settings and use it

Comment: Use a different sync program that installs and that you can schedule.  Sync Back Pro is excellent.

Comment: sync back pro paid one..will see..but im just curious there are many arcade games to which are available in click and play mode..could those be run as service? i did see the video though

Comment: If it is an executable put a shortcut to it in the Startup folder for your user account.

Comment: I have been using Sync Back Pro for well over a decade. It is worth the cost for sure.

Comment: @Moab the program is as such I click it ,it opens and run then the moment i close its done no longer running ..even thought its an exe file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click My Computer > Manage > Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library

From there you can find 'Create Task' or 'Create Basic Task' either under the Action menu or under the Actions panel on the right.  Either should take you through the steps of what to run from where and when to run it.  The nice part is if you tire of the task you can always go back to the same place and disable it or change other parameters.